# request.function in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

What is `request.function` used for in `web2py` . I am a beginner to `web2y` and came across these lines in a tutorial

```
if not request.function=='first' and not session.visitor_name:
    redirect(URL('first'))
```

What is `request.function` used for?

Comment: What's wrong with [reading the documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#request)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [documentation.](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#request)

`request.function: the name of the requested function.`

So in your case.

```
if not request.function=='first' and not session.visitor_name:
    redirect(URL('first'))
```

it's checking to see if the name of the function is not `first`.